# How to upload an EXE to a pendrive?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have an EXE file that displays hello world. How do I upload it to a pendrive and make the app open whenever the pendrive is connected and how to make it close the EXE when it is disconnected?

Just a note, the program is written in Python, OS is Windows.

Comment: This kind of autorun is disabled by pretty much every operating system for security reasons and has been for the last 20 years.

Comment: Oh, so can I make it run somehow? Or is it just impossible?

Comment: @Jotham - What operating system?  What is possible will depend on that factoid.  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Google "USB car park" for why this is set to not auto-run by default.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: The ability to automatically run an optical disk, which is disabled by default, but it still can be enabled. However, I believe the ability to automatically run a program on an removable storage drive, cannot be disabled.  **It's extremely dangerous to enable.**

Comment: Ok how do I do it?